# Writing MS-DOS programs using a Windows environment

Tags: dos, assembly

is there any way to write 16-bit MS-DOS programs using a Windows environment? I mean, without using a DOSBox + for instance Turbo Assembler and TurboC.

My requirement is to be able to run the program on a 386 running a version of MS-DOS. This could be achieved using DOSBox but I want to write the program in a Windows environment to be able to use my favourite editor and tools.

The program should be in C and assembler (or just assembler). Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[1] Use DOSBOX, but follow this...

http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/MOUNT

...to share files with your favorite editor. Of course this would mean that you will need to switch to DOSBOX for compilation.

[2] Use a cross platform compiler like OpenWatcom...

http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Detailed_Contents

.. and tweak your editor/tools to call the right parameters for the compiler :-)

Comment: btw, you only need to use [1] or [2] whichever you like most... not both ;-)

Comment: I will try with OpenWatcom. I was looking at the OpenWatcom compiler before asking here, but I didn't figure out if a Windows build was able to create non-Windows executables. Thanks :)